# Search is not working although item exists in DB

Tags: php, search, scope, controller, laravel-6

I am using laravel 6 : need user to find records by search bar, but it shows **No Available Records**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL5y6.jpg)
***this in my model:Category model:***

```
public function scopeWhenSearch($query, $search)
{
    return $query->when($search, function ($q) use($search){
            return $q->where('name','like','%$search%');
    });

}   //end of scopeWhenSearch
```

Then in my controller I used in the index when search function:categoryController

```
public function index()
{
    //

    $categories= Category::whenSearch(request()->search)->paginate(2);
    return view('dashboard.categories.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'%$search%'` is literally searching for the string `$search`, not whatever `$search` contains... Using `'`(single quotes) in PHP doesn't extract the value from the variable, you need to concatenate the value or use `"`(double quotes):

```php
return $query->when($search, function ($q) use($search){
   return $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
   // or use "
   // return $q->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
});
```

Comment: THANKS It ITS WORKING

Comment: You're welcome! Please use the upvote/accept answer functionality to express your thanks and properly close your question.